# Run Maven Build after Existing Maven Build in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Say i have two Maven Build Configurations in Eclipse for Projects 'A' and 'B' where both of them are for two **independent** **Projects**

Is there a way using which i could *execute Maven Build for Project 'B' after successful completion of Project 'A'*?

I see options to add *Parameters under 'A' Maven Build --> Main Tab* but not sure how to use it.

Please let me know in case I am missing anything...

EDIT:

Adding description to my existing Problem statement
Say i have below 3 projects

1. Project Foo
2. Project Bar
3. Project Alpha
4. Project Parent

Now, Alpha is my main EAR which contains both **Foo** and **Bar**.
 **Parent** is our *Parent Project*

My Build versions are always by default 1(so no version issues)
I did few *changes* in in **Project Bar**, i want that if i execute Maven *Build* on **Project Bar**, Maven *Build* for Project **Alpha** should be **auto triggered**.

Just to add here, i wanna *refrain* my self for running **Build on Parent Project**

Thanks in Advance,
Varun

Comment: Add dependency or module in B project  it is coming A Project

Comment: Since both are independent why you need one to be done before other. If they are dependant then there are ways to build one before another that you can find easily in stackoverflow

Comment: @santoshkumar edited my question please let me know if it adds further sense to the question :)

Comment: Think about using multi module projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If eclipse is not your concern and you just want to build your projects one after each other than one tricky way you can try by creating a batch which will build the projects.

Take a look on below sample batch which I tried for myself,

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "CODEBASE=C:\project_workspace"
SET "JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\1.7.0.25-x64"
SET "MAVEN_HOME=C:\Maven\Maven3"            

SET "PROJECTA_LOC=%CODEBASE%\ProjectA"
SET "PROJECTB_LOC=%CODEBASE%\ProjectB"

SET MVN_CMD=call mvn clean install -DskipTests -U

REM -- Environment Details --
ECHO CODEBASE: %CODEBASE%
ECHO JAVA_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%
ECHO MAVEN_HOME: %MAVEN_HOME%

REM -- project location  --
ECHO PROJECTA_LOC: %PROJECTA_LOC%
ECHO PROJECTB_LOC: %PROJECTB_LOC%

SET PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%MAVEN_HOME%/bin;
ECHO %PATH%

REM -- Calling Project A maven build
CD %PROJECTA_LOC% 
%MVN_CMD%

REM -- Calling Project B maven build
CD %PROJECTB_LOC% 
%MVN_CMD%
```

Hope it helps

EDIT: Changed Project B's name in comment

Comment: Thanks, will Test and let you know. Cheers